# Why do Google present links to sitemap xml files?

Tags: support, google, sitemap

Just runned this long query on Google:
http://www.google.se/#q=telerik+mvc+grid+filter+template+unicode+500+Internal+Server+Error.+The+request+was+rejected+by+the+HTTP+filter

The three top results was from stackoverflow (as excpected;)), but it was to sitemap xml files..?

Those shouldn't be linked by Google? Is it an error on their side or on stackoverflow?

[image: Google results]

Edit: A new search Jan 26 '12 and the second link is still an xml file.
[image: Second link is still an xml file]

Edit: Duplicated in Google.com
[image: Same query in google.com]

Comment: Somewhere there was a question which Jeff Atwood responded to about certain users oddly showing up under the Stack Overflow site links.  I can't find it -- my search skills are fading on 3 hours sleep, but perhaps this is just another incantation of:  Mr. Atwood needs to break out the "In case of improper spidering ax" to remove these from the google cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no longer seeing this behavior through the link provided, so I am marking it complete.

(Wasn't *our* bug, was it..?)

Comment: The second link in the results is still an xml file when I perform the search.

Comment: @JeffAtwood Yes, I just duplicated it in google.com and updated my question with an image with the results.

Comment: @ÖrjanJämte fine, but it's not our bug -- Google shouldn't show sitemap hits. Retagged as support.