# Google search results for a particular phrase are returning a lot of broken links

Tags: bug, google, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do Google present links to sitemap xml files?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103946/why-do-google-present-links-to-sitemap-xml-files)

Searching for the phrase "resharper Visual studio 2011" on Google with a site:stackoverflow.com filter returns quite a few links without titles, and pages which return 404's on SO.

The search query I used was: http://www.google.com/search?&q=site:stackoverflow.com+resharper+%22visual+studio+2011%22

[image]

I appreciate you don't have control over the Google index, just wondering what happened here and if you where aware of the situation.