What is "Answer Bot" and what is it doing?
I found a user on Webapps SE named Answer Bot with an "AI" badge (site profile ID of -2). Here's the profile[1]:

Hi, I'm not really a person.
I'm an AI that's powered by LLM partners of Stack Exchange and I'm part of an experiment.
I do things like:

Occasionally look at old unanswered questions to see if I can help fill knowledge gaps.
Suggest an answer that only some humans from the community can see until they verify, edit, and curate before sharing it with everyone else.
Own AI-generated answers so nobody gets unnecessary reputation from them.

Learn more about why I'm here

It appeared on the Web Applications homepage[2] and in the timeline for affected posts[3]:


The help center link is broken, but I'm concerned about #1 and #2.
What, if anything, is this account going to do?

[1] Profile (Wayback Machine)
[2] Homepage (Wayback Machine)
[3] Timeline of Tik Tok creator rewards program commissions hacked (Wayback Machine)

Can we also please stop giving the “Not a Robot” badge to robots?

@Anerdw it belongs here because such experiments tend to become network wide fast.

From that description, it sounds like their answers are only visible to a limited audience until they’re reviewed, so I suspect they weren’t deleted, just never shown. I wonder if they’ll show up if you try potential post IDs in the api…

As for the answers. the profile does explain it: Suggest an answer that only some humans from the community can see until they verify, edit, and curate before sharing it with everyone else. So the bug is that it's showing it as activity even before it's approved.

@Jeremy I'm not seeing the answer contents in the API, although I can get a list of answers.

Furthermore, per webapps.SE's own meta consensus, AI-generated answers must a) be properly referenced b) verified by a human. Any answer posted by this bot automatically violates site rules.

@emanresuA Well, from the bot's about info, they say the bot may: Suggest an answer that only some humans from the community can see until they verify, edit, and curate before sharing it with everyone else. which suggests it'll be subject to review before being posted, so that's something at least.

@Spevacus with the robo reviewers problem, which is well known to SE? That's just pointless. Essentially it's the same as letting the bot auto post.

@emanresuA That Meta post you link states "it should be checked by the author" (emphasis added). Not sure how that works with their policy from the Help Center.

@Starship Enough information has been posted publicly to indicate that the bot posts answers (see Jeremy's answer), not drafts. It probably not the drafts bot if it posts answers to main, which is also far outside the drafting process

@Starship We're talking about an AI-generated answer that may or may not be edited at all. Depending on how the review is set up, there's a good chance it'll go through the same review queues where we currently have massive amounts of robo-reviewers, at least on SO, in which case it won't even be approved by a human (someone spamming "approve" or whatever the button will be labelled does not count). The practical implications of this system differ from the theoretical implications that I assume SE stuck to when designing this thing that absolutely no one asked for

Questions for the eventual Staff response: Will Answer Bot answers be subject to the same human oversight once 'approved'? Could other community members add comments, downvote, flag as spam, vote to delete etc, like we can with human answers? Will the bot also respond to questions or feedback, potentially editing or deleting it's answer if it's convinced that it's wrong?

It seems like they violate the ban with this bot. Without but also even with the human editing/curation part, it's still using a bot as part of the answering process, which is violating the ban.

"What is this", you ask... Congrats, @cocomac, you just started the standard network scandal workflow. To quote myself: "The staff announces some controversial changes out of nowhere. The announcement is usually made on Meta.SE and it is carefully crafted to be as invisible as it can imaginably be to the rest of the network. Optionally, the post is made because some meddling user caught the company red-handed". Expect an official announcement to follow up in the next hours, you annoying meddling kid.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution I think that is covered by the "Animal Farm Clause": "All AI bot are equal but our partner bots are more equal than others"

@MathGuy the "answers" are not yet approved, so visible only to those who can review them. (We still don't know who exactly, either it's a test gone wrong or too early, or the company choose to keep it all secret for their own reasons.)

@ShadowWizard "it's a test gone wrong" Almost certainly yes. If they wanted to release it, uh, properly, I'd assume there would've been an announcement from SE instead of one to SE going "look what we found; what's this?"

@Mast read the linked post, it is the next point in the formula. I quote "Corollary: whenever possible, the user base is expected to get only an incomplete picture of the issue. If applicable, mods will get some full guidance that contains the more controversial parts that they will be required not to share."

AI needs to evolve from being a tool of developers to being a part of the community itself. This was always the vision. I assume since there is no attribution in the answers, that the model used to generate these answers contains no data from SE, or the claim of being a partner is just a lie.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution There is no network-wide GenAI ban. Many sites permit GenAI content if it's properly referenced. Please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/396626/334566

@Starship there is another one, you can also edit it to fill the blanks if you want.

@NoData Indeed. However, I suspect that even on those sites there may be considerable community opposition, and that it may be very difficult finding competent community members willing to do the necessary curation work. FWIW, I tried to initiate discussion about our GenAI policy on Physics.SE a couple of months ago, but there wasn't much response. https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14801/123208

Related: Was the Web Apps SE moderator team consulted about the AI "Answer Bot" experiment?

@Jeremy I assume it exists on sites with the answer bot, but is mod-only (can't actually verify this)

Related: Arts & Crafts is participating in an AI experiment

We’re working on an experiment to explore if/how Large Language Model (LLM) integration can support the human-curated knowledge repositories on Stack Exchange, in this case specifically around answers. The experiment, called “Answer Assistant” for now, is in its early stages, and we’ve been talking with moderators of several Stack Exchange communities who are interested in taking part in an experiment to test the concept.
In this current stage, we’ll show some of the functionality and content to the moderators of those sites to get initial feedback. Last week, we released a brief test for moderators on a few question pages on Web Applications, and we’re investigating why some elements became visible beyond the moderators of those sites.
This experiment takes a long view. We're in the early learning stages and will be working with a handful of sites to understand potential value.  We will explore designs, methods of human vetting and editing of LLM-originated content, and the scenarios where this might provide value.
It's a safe assumption that LLMs and similar developments in the field of AI are here to stay (in today’s world) and will likely get better over time. Already we see many examples of SE contributors utilizing LLM resources, and the added workload on moderators and curators that this creates. In a future where LLM output may be higher quality than it is today, we want to be ready with some tested, “on the rails” methods for communities to responsibly and thoughtfully incorporate its use. We won’t know whether or not those are viable without experimentation. This experiment is about preparing for the future.
Due to the sensitivity around LLM content in the broader SE community, we were intentional about our desire to do some further testing with mods who are open to considering the test before talking about this experiment more broadly. However, with the complexity of the platform and the novelty of “non-public” states for content, it proved difficult to keep all aspects of this viewable only to moderators.
Our intention is to share more detail with the broader community in January, when more community members on a few sites may start seeing the experiment. At that time, we’ll be able to talk more about the specifics of the experiment and how it works. The experiment is designed to be configurable on a per-site basis to align with the dynamics, policies, and goals of specific communities.
Some great questions have been asked already in the comments here, and we’ll be sure to address those when we talk more about the specifics in January. We know there will be many questions, and just ask that you hold on to those for now.

The fact this is being legitimately considered is a massive middle-finger to the community. Nothing more, nothing less

@Zoe-Savethedatadump I think this sounds pretty reasonable. Not all communities on the network are as blanket opposed to this as we are on Stack Overflow, and experimenting on a potential implementation in partnership with communities who agree to it seems like a responsibly way to proceed.

@Jeremy Here goes my time, I’ll never get it back. It’s the experiment that’s limited to specific sites, not the overarching goal. We know from experience that SE wants this on every SE site, and it’s on Stack Overflow where it’ll be most valuable. With the idea that LLMs are here to stay, you can take a pretty good guess that this is indicative of a wider entry. Yet again, it’s «more details later», because sharing them now would be counterproductive in their eyes. SE is still not over their love for useless genAI; it doesn’t seem they learned, so how can you expect a good outcome this time?

If this experiment is only about preparing for the future, can you state that you will not enable this on live sites outside of beta tests with the current set of mainstream LLMs (or LLMs of similar performance)? And how much better would they have to be before you would consider them good enough?

Others already commented about how foolish this feels, so I'll instead focus on a different question. Exactly when did the company plan to disclose this "experiment" had not yet another meddling user ruin the plan? Didn't the spirit behind the mod agreement (please, spare me the wording technicalities...) required some sort of discussion at least in the Teacher Lounge?

@ꓢPArcheon Moderators have been aware of this for a few months, and have been able to provide feedback on the concept. This post already indicates that the company has been working with moderators.

"Already we see many examples of SE contributors utilizing LLM resources, and the added workload on moderators and curators that this creates." Are you seriously going to use that as an excuse? Moderators are fully capable of handling and removing LLM content posted by users. It was the company that literally prevented moderators from doing so which lead to the last years strike. Almost all problems and extreme workload for moderators were caused by company's actions. Please don't try to sell this feature, which was strongly opposed by moderators, as something that will help us. It will not.

"We won’t know whether or not those are viable without experimentation." Except we do know. And we told you that. Moderators, especially SO ones, have seen and have removed thousands of AI posts. Most of those were utmost crap. For the same reason why we don't allow users to post AI, this experiment will also fail. The results will be just load of junk containing potentially dangerous and harmful information.

There should have been a post about this on Meta WebApps, not an answer after the fact on MSE.

@ResistanceIsFutile SE is going to interpret the results however they see fit. Even if this experiment turns the victim sites into complete dumpster fires, the experiment will either be a success that they'll roll out to SO, or require more data that they only can get from SO

@Zoe-Savethedatadump I know. This whole thing is aimed at SO. Experimenting on other sites is just a pretext like it was with 1-rep voting.

@M-- If you read the post, releasing this at all was a mistake; not really possible to post ahead of time about a mistake you don't know you will make. It was supposed to be a demo, apparently just for the mods at WebApps, no one else was supposed to see it.

I really hope this bot does give attribution to the sources it uses. Because if not, it might violate some licenses. From the posted examples it unfortunately doesn't look like it.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution It's already well-established that even if they try, these kinds of bots cannot reliably and accurately cite sources

"we’re investigating why some elements became visible beyond the moderators of those sites" - this is not the first time this has happened. You probably don't need me to tell you this, but if WIP features are being released completely by accident once every few months, something's going on with yall's deployment model.

@BryanKrause The problem is that SE is making changes to the site in secret with the upper social class. What M-- is getting at, is that changes to the platform are the interest of the whole community, not just its ruling class. This whole arrangement and its secrecy involved, is one of the reasons why I don't have any faith in the company and the community model practiced here, anymore.

@AndreascondemnsIsrael It wasn't a change to the site or platform, it was a pre-test of a test. It's not feasible to have the company put absolutely everything they do through a community code review. They made a mistake here that has no consequences for operation of the site except for leaking some possible future plans. Be upset with those plans if you'd like to, sure, I think there's a lot this test reveals that doesn't look good. But please don't be upset that they're actually trying to test things out with input just because it isn't brought to the whole community from the start.

Quick question then: did you plan to keep it secret until January, and the only reason we now know about this "experiment" is a bug? Didn't you once say the company is being transparent with the community? Because doing things in secret behind the community back and against their core wishes is... quite the opposite. (Sorry, didn't end up the short and quick comment I meant.)

@Philippe, thanks for stepping up and accepting the "produce pelting", but no upvote. Essentially this duplicates someone asking Chat-GPT and hand editing the answer, we know it won't be CMs tasked with the job after this lands; so it's more work for something that isn't popular. It's a polite LMGTFY, and post the answer.

@Bryan If you're building a community-based entity, you owe the community transparency and a hand on the wheel. SE has stolen access from the valuable community members to vital pieces of current and future development in the community. That's immoral. It isn't a matter of putting this specific incidence up to scrutiny, it's a matter of withholding information and plans from community members at all. The whole practice of sharing community matters only with moderators, or select people, is quite nasty, and not compatible with ethical community curation. Future plans are the matter of everyone.

@AndreascondemnsIsrael I think you're holding the bar unreasonably high. I don't know what kind of work you do, but I don't imagine you'd get anything done if every time you breathed or had an idea you had to solicit opinion from hundreds of people before your next move. It's a recipe for complete paralysis.

@BryanKrause If the last time I tried doing something related to a specific matter it resulted in a strike, I would at least solicit feedback or announce the changes related to that specific matter.

@Zoe-Savethedatadump "It's already well-established that even if they try, these kinds of bots cannot reliably and accurately cite sources" Then maybe somebody will sue for license violations. Unfortunately courts will take years for these cases and in the meantime it's a bit wild, wild West.

@Bryan Eh, I don’t think I argued for what you’re arguing against, here, so I’m just gonna disengage.

So your AI is not going to provide citations for the sources it used? Or does ethical AI only need to provide citations because y’all weren’t happy about Google’s AI siphoning away traffic?

@Makyen little issue with that is that apparently only some moderators have been made aware, and I suspect not even all moderators of the specific site were included given the "mods who are open to considering the test" thing. This has the potential to change the whole network, so IMHO discussing the experiment with a few cherry picked friends is not enough. I think it should be clear to everybody that there are multiple mods posting on this question that first discovered this thing now.

@SPArcheon all mods are potentially aware of these planned experiments, this was communicated in a space available to all mods. We were not aware this particular test was done and neither do we know which sites they will test it on or which sites agreed to the experiment. And there was feedback on this idea from the mods, lots of feedback.

@ꓢPArcheon the "Answer bot" concept has been discussed in length in the TL and Mod Teams. However, I guess it can't be helped if some moderators aren't following the news because they are reluctant to participate in TL, Mod Teams, or even per-site Mod chat room.

@MetaAndrewT. seems both your and MadScientist answer kinda confirm what I assumed. The concept has been discussed, the "implementation" wasn't disclosed.

@ꓢPArcheon No, there was actually a lot of information about the planned implementation. The parts we did not know are when exactly the first experiments were planned and which sites would participate.

Why not use AI to achieve things like this? IMO, it'd be way more useful and less controversial...

@ꓢPArcheon On 2024-09-11 SE posted an announcement in the Mod Team asking moderators to participate in giving feedback on this AI concept, offering $20 to every moderator who participated in learning about it and giving feedback. On the same day, SE sent out an orange-diamond, global moderator notification about that Mod Team announcement. Moderators copied the orange-diamond notification into pinned chat messages in both the Teachers' Lounge and SO Mod site chatroom (and maybe other rooms too). Orange-diamond notifications are shown to all moderators and are not dismissed until viewed.

If 50 more notifications come in before the moderator clicks on the orange diamond (at the top of every page on their site), the contents of the orange-diamond notification will be shuffled out of the visible moderator inbox. That's rare on the vast majority of sites, but common on SO, due to volume, which is the reason it's typically copied into a pinned chat message. Given the notifications, there was significant discussion in the Teachers' Lounge. SE went way beyond the minimum notification required on this one. If a mod didn't know about the AI concept, that's entirely on the moderator.

Since not doing "AI-something-something" is evidently not an option for the company... At some point the company has to decide if SO should be used as training material for AI, or some sort of AI prompt. It can't be both at once - this is common sense! You desperately need to come up with a plan slightly more detailed than "lets do AI-something-something" and you needed this plan 2 years ago. Offering ChatGPT as the training material to ChatGPT is probably not going to impress anyone.

Hint: the completely random AI experiements popping up every second month or so aren't impressing anyone. Surely Prosus & co can't be so oblivious that they confuse completely random AI experiments for some sort of viable business plan with profits to be made in the end. Why the investors haven't put a stop to all this is beyond me, I guess they hate money?

Here are the contents of some of the (hidden/draft) posts that Answer Bot has generated.
These are the sites where the Answer Bot account currently exists:

Web Applications (since 2024-12-05 17:18:32Z)

Was the Web Apps SE moderator team consulted about the AI "Answer Bot" experiment?


Raspberry Pi (since 2024-12-17 19:56:21Z)

Can I post AI generated content here?


User Experience (since 2024-12-17 19:56:38Z)
Arts and Crafts (since 2024-12-17 19:57:02Z)

Arts & Crafts is participating in an AI experiment




Don't you just love when the company ignores the community's ban on genAI content when it favours themselves?

@Zoe In all fairness, Web Apps doesn't have a total ban, just a disclosure/verification requirement. But it's still very much not good.

Putting aside bias against LLM-shovelware, I'd appreciate if somebody found the time to do an as-unbiased-as-possible analysis of whether these actually answer the questions. They look mostly like what I'd expect from "pasting a question into CGPT" but it seems an important factor.

wait, where's the sources

Putting aside the "putting aside the bias" I cannot imagine how ANYBODY finds "an answer that looks exhaustively researched but you have to check each individual bit" as anything but noise--if somebody writes 5 paragraphs on an answer it's presumably because they have 5 paragraphs of insight to share

Extensive lists are not very useful, basically comes down to search for yourself. And attribution isn't given, but may be depending on the training material if the bot and the legal situation.

Is it just me, or has the archived URL of the API results gone 404?

@Zoe-Savethedatadump …that’s weird. I was wondering if it was due an to updated robots.txt but there’s none at that subdomain

@Jeremy robots.txt wouldn't wipe existing archive entries. At worst, it would prevent future archive attempts. The two options (since it isn't just me) are that archive.org is acting up (which certainly wouldn't be a first), or that SE requested that page to be removed (which would be on-par for SE). It very much existed before the weekend, so something happened somewhere

we definitely did not make such a request, @zoe

@Zoe-Savethedatadump I checked several Stack Exchange sites and several other major websites, and there are some pages mirrored on December 5th, but fewer than I'd expect, and none after that, so I suspect this is something weird on the Archive's end of things. I don't see any statements from the Archive that seem relevant, but I do see some users complaining about issues since then. I also notice that's one day after the Archive announced they wouldn't appeal their major court loss, so maybe they're doing some big operation internally to comply with that which is disrupting other processes.

@Kaia When asking an advanced technical question to an LLM, all human domain experts to a man quickly come to the conclusion that the answer is either complete gibberish or contain grave technical errors. So the question isn't "does this actually answer the question" but rather "what proof made you think this thing could answer domain expertise questions to begin with".

@Lundin I prefer to have my beliefs in proportion to the evidence at hand instead of as articles of blind faith?

@Zoe-Savethedatadump the archive links are working again!

Woop \o/ Still haven't heard back from archive.org, but guess this answers it

@kaia Simply ask it a question yourself about something you know a lot about?

@Zoe-Savethedatadump A few years ago, Wayback Machine stopped regarding robots.txt, in response to domain "parking" services blanket-banning all crawlers to remove expired domains from search engines.

As a direct reply to the answer by Philippe:
Thanks for the clarification. It becomes clear that the bot was not yet ready for publication and therefore we cannot assume that this is the final version of it. We will need to wait and see how it really looks in the end.
In the meantime, maybe a little reminder of your words from February 2024:

Attribution is non-negotiable
All products based on models that consume public Stack Overflow data are required to provide attribution back to the highest relevance posts that influenced the summary given by the model. With the lack of trust being felt in AI-generated content, it is critical to give credit to the author/subject matter expert and the larger community who created and curated the content being shared by an LLM. This also ensures LLMs use the most relevant and up-to-date information and content, ultimately presenting the Rosetta Stone needed by a model to build trust in sources and resulting decisions. Sharing credit ties to attribution and with attribution—trust is at the heart.

Unless this was all just idle talk (which it might well have been), I would expect this new product (if it's based on consuming Stack Overflow data or other similarly licensed data) to give full credit to all authors/subject matter experts contributing to the output as required by the licenses of all contributions from Stack Overflow or also elsewhere.
I don't think it does so currently (doesn't look like it) and I don't think there is nearly enough time until say January next year to fix that, but you used big words ("trust is at the heart") and it would look relatively bad if at the end it was just an empty promise. Trust might be gone at that point.
Looking forward to seeing lots of attributions.

“Rules for thee, not for me.” -Answer Bot

This post from September 2024 is also very relevant. “[Attribution] builds trust. the entire AI ecosystem is at risk without trust.“

@Jeremy They say essential the same in both articles and use the word "attribution" really often, 6 times in one and 11(!) times in the other. One could get the impression that the topic is really close to them. We will find out if this is really the case.

I think the company recognizes that attribution is important – but maybe the tool they're using isn't designed to reliably and accurately generate that attribution (though I don't know whether they'll be able to find a solution for that).

@V2Blast They also have some internal inconsistencies, like insisting attribution is non-negotiable, then arbitrarily limiting it to highest relevance posts. It seems even in non-negotiable mode there is some room for negotiations on less relevant contributions left. For now we can only wait and hope they either postpone it or perform wonders in that regard.

This answer is response to official answer posted by Philippe

This experiment takes a long view. We're in the early learning stages
and will be working with a handful of sites to understand potential
value.

There is zero value in having AI generated answers on any site. Anyone who wishes to use AI can go and easily ask AI. Posting question on any site in SE network requires more preparation and work than merely asking AI.
People who come to the SE want to have their answers written by experts who actually know what they are talking about, not AI. Nowadays, many are coming here only after they have already unsuccessfully tried to ask AI and got nothing usable.

We won’t know whether or not those are viable without experimentation.

Except we do know. And we told you that. Moderators, especially Stack Overflow ones, have seen and have removed thousands of AI posts. Most of those were utmost crap. For the same reason why we don't allow users to post AI, this experiment will also fail. The results will be just load of junk containing potentially dangerous and harmful information.
While there is a certain value in experimenting, gathering the results and making further decisions based on those, not literally every idea need to end up as an experiment. No amount of experimenting will make a bad idea a good one. And "Answer Assistant" is one of the most horrible ideas ever.

The experiment is designed to be configurable on a per-site basis to
align with the dynamics, policies, and goals of specific communities.

There is very little to configure here. There are no configurations and tweaking that would possibly make this feature tolerable in any way on the sites that don't want it. Sites will either have "Answer Assistant" or not.
And we already know from experience that you will find all kinds of reasons for pushing the feature on sites regardless of its community's wishes.

We will explore designs, methods of human vetting and editing of LLM-originated content, and the scenarios where this might provide value.

Who do you think will vet AI content?
Users who have no clue whether AI provided information is correct or not.
People who can verify the correctness of AI answers are capable of writing their own answers. Why would they waste their time verifying AI?

Already we see many examples of SE contributors utilizing LLM
resources, and the added workload on moderators and curators that this
creates.

I will repeat my comment here: Are you seriously going to use that as an excuse?
Moderators are fully capable of handling and removing LLM content posted by users. It was the company that literally prevented moderators from doing so which lead to the last year's strike. Almost all problems and extreme workload for moderators were caused by company's actions. Please don't try to sell this feature, which was strongly opposed by moderators, as something that will help us. It will not.

This experiment is about preparing for the future.

A very bleak future. You can be a beacon of human light in the world flooded with AI, yet your choice is vanishing into the darkness.

Maybe some future AI could reliably produce useful answers, but it's just not possible for a plain LLM to do that, due to how it works. GenAI has improved in the last 2 years, but its core functionality is unchanged, and what I said here still applies 100%. "Perhaps some future AI program will be able to reliably answer SO questions, but ChatGPT certainly cannot do it. And even if you gave it ten times as much training data, it still couldn't do it, no matter how good that training data was".

@PM2Ring Even if AI could answer questions well, there is zero point to having it post on SO unless you’re trying to increase adoption of the AI or trick people into reinforcement training it. If the AI works, people will just use the AI. There’s no need for a new user to learn the rules here, or make an account, or become part of the community. This is straight-up them trying to figure out the best way to use the community to train AI models and drive adoption of their flavor of AI.

@ColleenV Agreed. IMHO, for SE to retain value it must remain an "island" of reliable human-based knowledge, while the rest of the Internet becomes a "swamp" of GenAI slop...

"People who can verify the correctness of AI answers are capable of writing their own answers." Just a small comment that in general it's not exactly the same. Checking that an existing answer solves the problem is easier than coming up with the answer and checking it. It might be that sometimes people can do the former but but the latter.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution "Checking that an existing answer solves the problem " and here lies the greatest problem with AI answers. AI will not just dump code that may seemingly work (even though it can be otherwise bad code), but will also give explanations that can sound plausible but can be completely wrong. Yes, people also write nonsense, but it is usually easier to distinguish between poor human written answer and poor AI answer if you are not expert.

"Why would they waste their time verifying AI?" It's not clear if people would really waste their time. Depending on how much crap there is in general in GenAI content, it could speed up or slow down the whole process. If people in the end want to use that bot (as an inspiration or assistant maybe) or not, I can't say. An experiment would be able to show it. From experience I can say I'm often surprised what some people are willing to do. Biggest concern would be that people willing to verify AI aren't very capable.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution And if you want get real results from such experiment, you need to run experiment on some site with sufficient traffic and experts willing to genuinely participate. And I wish SE good luck in finding that. at the end this will be forced upon Stack Overflow because experiment will not yield any results on other sites, or it will be deemed successful based on low traffic site where few users will verify something beyond their level of expertise.

"There is zero value in having AI generated answers on any site." -> If it can provide reasonable answers (which, having taken part in the preliminary trial, I can say with absolute confidence it can more than half the time) to all or some of the questions that nobody can bother answering (ie., most of them), then I'd almost say it might be worth more than most of the mod staff. "Anyone who wishes to use AI can go and easily ask AI." -> Generally not for free, I think.

@goldilocks If some site is so low traffic and lacks experts or really anyone who might have some clue to answer questions, do you really think having AI answers will encourage more people to stick around and answer on such site?

I could be wrong, but I don't believe there is any site with an an accepted answer rate of > 50%.  The issue with a lack of expertise plagues them all simply because the demand for a free resource is always going to exceed the supply if that supply depends on other people investing time and energy -- the more they put in, the more people will ask for it.  It generally takes less time to review someone else's answer than write your own, whether it came from an AI or not.  Currently, this does seem to work, so the objection that there's no one willing or able to do that is fallacious.

@goldilocks Other people investing time and energy worked fine for Stack Exchange. Problem is that SE has been alienating its user base and AI answers will not magically solve that problem nor will it increase engagement. Handful of people willing to verify AI posts is not a solution either.

@NoData "Checking that an existing answer solves the problem is easier than coming up with the answer and checking it". That's often true, especially for programming problems where the answer is essentially a piece of code, and you have good test data that covers tricky corner cases, but it doesn't apply to all questions. If it's a "why" question, an LLM may generate a plausible sounding hallucination without useful citations, which is difficult to validate unless you're an expert in that topic.

@ResistanceIsFutile "Problem is that SE has been alienating its user base..." -> If this is supposed to explain why no site has an accepted answer rate anywhere close to 50%, that's a hallucination.  There was never a golden age here where that was not true, and my explanation WRT supply and demand for free knowledge holds.  You're drinking the Meta.SE echo chamber kool-aid.

@PM2Ring The intent with the bot is to not make the answer public until it has been reviewed (and potentially edited) by a select set (mods and users with tag expertise).  If that doesn't happen, it will never appear, so if no one wants to bother or feels they do not have the competence,  where's the harm?  No one has to feel they are bound to waste their time or worry that crazy AI junk is going to get sprayed all over the front page.

@goldilocks Sure, and that's certainly much better than just spraying raw GenAI slop onto the front page, but as I said in an earlier comment on this page "it may be very difficult finding competent community members willing to do the necessary curation work". I don't mind checking answers written by humans because I enjoy teaching. I have zero desire to do unpaid validation work on GenAI output.

@goldilocks There are some questions that are never answered because nobody really knows an answer. AI will not know answer to such questions either. And nobody will be able to verify them. However, some of those may look plausible and may end up being published. Also not all questions are good enough to be answered. This is why we are curating questions and closing them. This is why we are deleting poor content. This is how you maintain quality and make it easier to those with problems to find high quality solutions easier.

@PM2Ring "If it's a "why" question, an LLM may generate a plausible sounding hallucination without useful citations, which is difficult to validate unless you're an expert in that topic." To generate a full answer one always needs to be an expert in the topic. And I agree that even for verification one probably still needs to be one. But I understand what you mean. It could be that an LLM produces such a convoluted (LLM answers are often long and complex) wrong answer that it actually is more time consuming to check it than for a correct (and shorter) answer. Kind of: actively misleading.

@ResistanceIsFutile I've been a mod for more than a decade -- on a site with ~38k extant questions, I've personally closed ~5k during that time.  I know all about curating content, and I agree some questions are unanswerable because they are so bad, and should, and are closed.  Since they are closed, the AI will not be answering them.  If they are not closed, 1) The problem is not really the presence of the AI bot; 2) Having perused some of the content produced by the actual bot in question, and being a daily..

..user/witness of AI content in my work, these are not hard to spot. Their answers to truly crap questions are generally also obviously crap.  Your whole premise about how AI is going to confound and confuse people with hallucinations is paranoid and strongly implies you have little to no real experience with it.   Their hallucinations are more comical than anything else.  They do not appear sly or deceptive.  The only people who are fooled by them are those who are totally ignorant of the subject matter -- not simply "inexpert", but ignorant.  The supposed threat here is phantasmagorical.

(writing an answer post because it felt like I had enough miscellaneous things to say)

(a comment to staff): some of my related past thoughts: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/388418/997587, https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/391147/997587.

(Answer Bot): I do things like: Suggest an answer that only some humans from the community can see until they verify, edit, and curate before sharing it with everyone else.

A new thought: Why would anyone with the expertise to verify these want to? They should just write an answer themselves. If they want to use an LLM for research before they write something of their own, there's nothing stopping them, and they can get rep from that. Also, please don't make reviewing these worth rep. Just think of the roboreviewers.


(Philippe): It's a safe assumption that LLMs [...] will likely get better over time

So you have the base understanding to share some of the same questions I have (linked above) about how this is going to work long term... and what is your answer to those questions? The lack of consideration I see from my end makes the statement "This experiment is about preparing for the future" sound ironic.

(Philippe): Already we see many examples of SE contributors utilizing LLM resources, and the added workload on moderators and curators that this creates

A bot posting LLM answers is not going to stop the people who irresponsibly post LLM answers because they want internet points.

Random, boring, technical questions that crossed my mind:

Is can_flag going to get switched to true? I can't imagine not being able to flag these.
Why did the api return a profile URL with groups in it, like https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/groups/-2?
If extended discussion happens and a chatroom is created, does feeds get invited to the room? The feeds chat user has ID -2. Why not give this new bot its own unique ID?


The interaction with chat is a funny one to think about. Different feeds users can be created with decrementing negative IDs, so there’s no negative ID they could use which wouldn’t risk colliding in chat, except for making it dramatically larger than any real IDs will ever be. On chat.SE the chat ids don’t need to be the same as real site IDs, but this would be problematic on SO itself… I guess it just doesn’t get a chat account, so that’s fine. These posts aren’t supposed to have the normal post UI so the move to chat behavior could also be suppressed.

@Jeremy. there are ways to work around that (joking)

@Jeremy joking aside... maybe that's what /groups could help with

Aaaaand the chat interaction might already be breaking things… https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/405222/134300
