Creating a dedicated user for a feed posted into a chat room doesn’t work anymore
After a feed has been added to a chatroom, users with sufficient privilege could create a dedicated user for it (to make it more distinct) using the create user button next to the feed in the respective list. This doesn’t work anymore.
Instead, create user redirects me to “We are currently offline for maintenance – Gateway time-out” after half a minute. (This is incorrect, there is currently no maintenance and the rest of chat is working.) Other moderators could reproduce this problem, so it’s not just me.

The call to https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/makeFeedUser never runs to completion. In case this is useful for diagnosing purposes: Ray ID: 8f6fc67559b406ce

The obvious candidates for what caused the problem, depending on how often the capability to create a new Feeds user is attempted, are the transition to using Cloudflare; the transition of moving chat to a cloud-based service, rather than hosting it in-house; and the creation of Answer Bot at user ID -2, which is the same user ID as the first Feeds user. [While user IDs are only loosely coupled on chat.SE, they are fairly tightly coupled on chat.SO and chat.MSE, so the relevance of having a main site user at user ID -2 is unclear, but a possible issue and the most recent thing that happened.]

related question about answer bot: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/405058/997587
