# Title text of Stack Overflow question on Google is prefixed with the post's score

Tags: discussion, google

I have entered the following into a Google search:

`find attribute beautifulsoup site:stackoverflow.com`

The first result was a link to the question on Stack Overflow titled ["How to find tags with only certain attributes - BeautifulSoup"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933863/how-to-find-tags-with-only-certain-attributes-beautifulsoup), however, on Google, there was a number "89" before the question title: "89 How to find tags with only certain attributes - BeautifulSoup".

Why does the number "89" appear before the question title on Google? it's not actually part of the questions title.

[image]

Comment: Until the 21st of march that was the vote count on the question. Now I imagine Google doesn't index it that often, so hence it retains that value. The first answer also has a score greater then that, but had it for a much longer time now, about june of last year.

Comment: This was addressed by [this old Q&A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135906/282094), and a [relevant link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/136414/282094) in a comment; but that's 10 years ago, it's fair to ask again. Following the links results in this [closer duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115634/282094). Additional information: [URL Formats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/332251/282094).

Comment: Already reported and [tag:status-declined] on MSO: [Google shows number of favorites in SO search result](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342226/4642212), [Why do I see a number in the title while googling this question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405081/4642212), [Google search result actually spells out the input controls of Stack Overflow. Is this Google's fault or bug in Stack Overflow?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334116/4642212).